# Microservices end points accessible on Internet

Tags: rest, spring-boot, architecture, microservices

We have a MicroService based Architecture where each service has a REST End point. These services talk to each other via REST.

However I noticed that a lot of developers have directly started calling these Services in the Javascript code of our Web Application. I want to know if it is recommended to access these MicroServices over the Internet OR they should be hidden behind a Facade layer. Of course all the end points are authenticated but all Web application users can find these end points once they do a F12.

thanks,

Abhi

Comment: It depends on your need but I'm curious to know if you have an onboarding process to authenticate someone's access to your APIs? Do you use OAuth to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would not do that for the following reasons

1. **Security**. You are exposing your endpoint as is and it allow other people to know quite a lot about your endpoints then what you rather want them to know. Authentication is ok, but are still open for DDOS for your individual services, out of turn calls, unexpected load etc.
2. **Service Discovery**. By allowing access to the endpoints directly you are basically forcing dev to bind themselves with a given URL. This may work but since it is restricting you to make changes in future to your URL etc its better not to do it. By having a layer in between you will be required to change one url if ever required
3. **Code Duplication** There are quite a few cross cutting concerns when it comes to URL handling like request logging, https stripping, authentication, prevention of DDOS, request limiting etc. By having one common layer before your services you can manage all these at that one place rather than doing each of them for each services

If you think any of these are or could be major concerns that you should add an additional layer in between and route your internet facing api via that.